# clang erroneously prefixing source files

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

When I build my (Swift) Xcode project I get the following error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/path/to/DerivedData/MyProject-btmqlitphlzsmgfdbhbzoygglxgm/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/MyProject/MyProject.MySourceFile+CoreDataProperties.m'
clang: error: no input files
```

Notice the file it is complaining about is `MyProject.MySourceFile+CoreDataProperties.m`. If I go to that directory in the derived data I see the *actual* file is `MySourceFile+CoreDataProperties.m` without the `MyProject` prefix.

This might have something to do with Cocoapods; my Podfile is as follows

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'MyProject' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'XCGLogger', :git => 'https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger.git', :branch => 'swift_3.0'
end
```

I have recently migrated my project to Xcode 8 + Swift 3 and pulled in the updated dependencies for Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was unable to pin down exactly what the issue was but possibly something to do with name spaces and core data. Probably triggered by my migration of this project to Xcode 8/Swift 3.

What I did to move forward was to delete *all* my core data model definitions in Xcode (but **not** the source files). I then painstakingly re-created them all and now my projects builds as normal.

Comment: *Please* file a bug report about this (https://bugreport.apple.com), and if possible attach your project in the broken state (before you re-created the model).

Comment: Sure, I can checkout out the broken state via Git easily enough. I will submit a bug report with my full project (warts and all) soon.

Comment: @JackLawrence I've submitted a bug report (28536844) in the hopes it'll be useful. That report contains archives of my project in both the working (Xcode 7.3) and non-working (Xcode 8) state.